# WPF satellite assemblies not picked up

Tags: wpf, localization, satellite-assembly

I have a demo app, and in it I use a 3rd party library that has several languages. To test whether the localization works, I set the CurrentUICulture to dutch:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("nl-NL");
```

I also set a breakpoint on the Properties.Resources.Get[xxx] so I can see what is going on. So, when I hit that breakpoint, I notice these modules are loaded:

```
output\Catel.Windows.dll
output\nl\Catel.Windows.resources.dll
```

Which seems good (he picked up the nl language, and loaded the satellite assembly as module). However, the resource manager keeps returning the english version of the resource...

When I open the dutch satellite assembly in reflector, I can see dutch resources, so the satellite assembly looks fine.

Comment: ok, I at least found the issue. In my assemblies, I put the translations in a subfolder of the Properties folder called Translations so my Properties folder doesn't get full of these files. However, that breaks the assemblies. Hopefully there is a way to put the translated files into a subfolder without causing the name to change...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I at least found the issue. In my assemblies, I put the translations in a subfolder of the Properties folder called Translations so my Properties folder doesn't get full of these files. However, that breaks the assemblies